# FetchRequest Sorted

Tags: sorting, core-data

Ooookay...
Maybe it's just too late... but I can not get this thing to work.
Actually the fetch ist working... but it's not sorted in any way !?
"zaehler" is an Int32 attribute- should work perfect !?

What am I doing wrong ?

```
static func getAllMaterialSorted() -> [MaterialMO] {

    var result = [MaterialMO]()
    let moc = AppDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MaterialMO> = MaterialMO.fetchRequest()

    let zaehler = NSSortDescriptor(key: "zaehler", ascending: false)
    let name = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [zaehler]

    do {
        result = try moc!.fetch(MaterialMO.fetchRequest()) as! [MaterialMO]
    } catch {
        print ("Cannot fetch employees.Error \(error)")
        return result
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: It is late - you are creating a new fetchRequest inline: `result= try moc!.fetch(MaterialMO.fetchRequest())` should be `result = try moc!.fetch(fetchRequest)`.

Comment: And you’re only adding one out of two sort descriptors to the array.